# How can I change the default placeholder text in the Disqus comment field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, disqus

I need to say something different than the "Leave a message..." in the screenshot below:

[image: Text I'm trying to change]

Disqus doesn't appear to offer any way to customize this and because they use an iframe embed I'm having a lot of trouble hacking the textarea with JS.

Does anyone know of a way to get around this? I'd rather not switch comment services but I'm worried that might be the only solution.

This is what I've tried so far without success:

```
// Change Disqus Placeholder
$('iframe[name*=DISQUS]').contents().find("form textarea.placeholder").attr('placeholder', 'test');
```

Comment: I checked the Disqus from http://disqus.com/.. it shows the placeholder text is inside the span.. So if possible please share at least view source part of your code....

Answer (score 1):

I'm hearing you cannot alter the content of an iFrame unless it's pointing at the same domain so the only solution is to attempt route the Disqus iFrame through a proxy on the same domain and then use JS to hack it from there.

Unfortunately that means for me the better solution is just to use a different service which is a massive bummer I hope they can resolve this soon.